# jqGrid 4.12 border disappearing in all browsers

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

https://staging.transporthub.co.uk/gridtest/jqgrid.htm

When clicking in the cell to edit the value the border at the right and bottom is disappearing. Is there a css issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please, don't use old versions of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). The current version of free jqGrid is 4.13.4. I recommend you to change the URLs to CDN (see [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)).

The reason of your problem is not depend from the choice of the version. Your demo contains the following customization:

```css
.ui-state-highlight {
    border:none!important; /* !!! it's the origin of your problem */
    background:none!important;
}
```

which is the origin of your problem. You use cell editing (`cellEdit: true`), which selects (set `ui-state-highlight` class) non-editable cells during editing. The usage `border:none!important;` in the above CSS rule removes the border of the cell. You should remove the CSS rule.